# Exercise: pullback in the category of R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, solution-verification, modules, pullback

True or False:

(i) It always exist the pullback of two morphisms $f:A \rightarrow C$ and $g:B \rightarrow C$ in the category of R-modules.

(ii) if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a homomorphism of R-modules then $(\text{Ker}(f), i,0)$ is the pullback of the morphisms $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $0:\{0\} \rightarrow B$ in the category of R-modules, where $i: \text{Ker}(f) \rightarrow A$ is the inclusion map and $\{0\}$ is the zero R-module.

Now, I've already proved the first item by showing that $(P,p,q)$ is the pullback of the two morphisms, with $$P=\left\{(a,b) \in A \times B:f(a)=g(b) \right\},$$ and $p: P \rightarrow A$, $q: P \rightarrow B$ defined as $p(a,b)=a$ and $q(a,b) = b$.

My question is, is the second item a direct consequence of the first one? I mean, if I have $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $0:\{0\} \rightarrow B$ then (with $A=A$ and $B=\{0\}$) by (i)
$$P=\left\{(a,b) \in A \times \{0\}:f(a)=0(b) \right\}=\left\{a \in A:f(a)=0_B \right\}= \text{Ker}(f).$$ Moreover $p(a,b)= p(a,0)=a$  is like $p(a) = a$ so in this case $p$ is the inclusion and $q(a,b) = q(a,0) = 0_B$ is always the projection in the second coordinate. So the pullback $(\text{Ker}(f), i,0)$ matches with the one established in the first item. Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, to formalize the "is like" try to prove the following: $(P,p,q)$ and $(P',p',q')$ are both pullbacks of the morphisms $A \stackrel f\to C \stackrel g\leftarrow B$ if and only if there is an isomorphism $\varphi : P \to P'$ so that $p' \circ \varphi = p$ and  $q' \circ \varphi = q$. In your case, $\varphi : \{(a,b) \in A \times \{0\}: f(a) = 0(b)\} \to \ker f$ is defined by $\varphi(a,b) = a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the second item is not a direct consequence of the *statement* of the first item, which just says that *some* pullback exists.  But you are correct that it does follow easily from the specific pullback that you proved works for the first item, since the kernel described in the second item is almost a special case of that construction.  However, it is not literally a special case: your equation $$\left\{(a,b) \in A \times \{0\}:f(a)=0_B \right\}=\left\{a \in A:f(a)=0_B \right\}$$ is not actually true since $A\times\{0\}$ is not the same thing as $A$!  Of course, they are isomorphic by ignoring the second coordinate in $A\times\{0\}$, but you do have to do a little work to check that you do still have a pullback when you replace $A\times\{0\}$ with $A$ in this way.

(On a related note, I would strongly recommend to avoid using phrases like "*the* pullback" in situations like this unless you are sure you know what you are doing.  There is not really such a thing as "*the* pullback"; instead, there are many different pullbacks, which are isomorphic to each other but not literally the same.  Talking about "the pullback" instead of "a pullback" is a good way to get yourself confused if you are not well-versed in working with these concepts.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that if I have two pullbacks $P$ and $P'$, then they're isomorphic. So for my proof, I can add the detail that $\varphi:\{(a,b) \in A \times \{0\}: f(a) = 0(b) \} \rightarrow \text{ker}f$ defined as $\varphi(a,b)=\varphi(a,0)=a$ is an isomorphism and so are the sets. Would that complete the proof?

Comment: No, you have to actually check that this isomorphism implies that $\ker f$ also satisfies the definition of the pullback (unless this is a theorem you have already seen).

Comment: In this course we've already seen that pullbacks are unique up to isomorphisms. In that case, I've proved that $\varphi$ works. But still I'm not sure if I understood the formality you propose, can you add details please?

Comment: What you need is a sort of converse of uniqueness up to isomorphism, that anything isomorphic to a pullback is also a pullback.  This is the "if" direction of the statement that azif00 commented above.